# How does this loop work even though counter isnt used?

Tags: php

i am exploring some old php files for the nostalgia, and i noticed this is what ive written before to fetch some records:

```
     <?php
        for ( $counter = 0; $row = mysqli_fetch_row( $result );++$counter )
        {
           print( "<tr>" );
           foreach ( $row as $key => $value )
           {
             if($key == '6')
             {
                if($value == '1'){print( "<td>12/9/15 6:00PM - 7:00PM</td>" );}
                if($value == '2'){print( "<td>12/9/15 7:00PM - 8:00PM</td>" );}
                if($value == '3'){print( "<td>12/9/15 8:00PM - 9:00PM</td>" );}
                if($value == '4'){print( "<td>12/10/15 6:00PM - 7:00PM</td>" );}
                if($value == '5'){print( "<td>12/10/15 7:00PM - 8:00PM</td>" );}
                if($value == '6'){print( "<td>12/10/15 8:00PM - 9:00PM</td>" );}
             }
             else
             {
                print( "<td>$value</td>" );
             }
           }
           print( "</tr>" );
        }
        mysqli_close( $database );
     ?>
```

i changed it to `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row( $result ))` and it works as well, as expected. i am just trying to understand the logic behidn how the for loop method works when `$counter` isnt being used...

[image: pic]

i am scrambling to understand why  i used this kind of logic, and how is it even working when `$counter` isnt even used for indexing or anything.

Comment: Are you asking how a php `while` loop works?

Comment: From the manual, it tests the middle expression and *If it evaluates to TRUE, the loop continues and the nested statement(s) are executed. If it evaluates to FALSE, the execution of the loop ends.*

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava oh im just asking how the for loop works even though $counter isnt being used at all.

Comment: @NigelRen oh im just asking how the for loop works even though $counter isnt being used at all.

Comment: Please read @NigelRen's comment carefully, or consult the manual for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to understand how this is working is by dissecting the `for` loop.

`for (<initialization>; <condition>; <update expresion>)`

In your case you have a counter that is being set initially, and incremented.

`for ( $counter = 0; $row = mysqli_fetch_row( $result );++$counter )`

You aren't using the counter, but it actually doesn't matter since the only thing that determines if the loop continues is if *the condition is **true***. Since eventually `mysqli_fetch_row` stops returning results, the loop will terminate. The `$counter` variable is unused and ignored for the purpose of the loop.

You could also rewrite your for loop to look like:

`for (;$row = mysqli_fetch_row( $result );)` and this would also work the same. But then, what is a `while` loop? It's just a for loop without an initialization and update expression. Thus you could rewrite this again as:

`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row( $result ))`

I hope this clears things up.